# Function for layering two rasters in R

Tags: raster, r, layers, overlay, hillshade

I am trying to layer a raster over a hillshade raster in the same way that I would do using the base R plot function (example code below) and export as a GeoTiff.

```
col_rmp <- c('#0180FF', '#0101FF', '#01FFFF', '#01FF01', '#FFFF01', '#FF0101', '#FF01FF', '#FFFFFF')
col_rmp_with_transparency <- unikn::usecol(pal = col_rmp, alpha = 0.5)
plot(hill, col=grey(0:100/100), legend=FALSE)
plot(test_raster, col=col_rmp_with_transparency, add=TRUE)
```

I am aware that two rasters can be overlain using the `raster::overlay` function which requires `raster::overlay(x, y, fun)` with X and y being raster objects and fun being a function. What function could I apply that would give me the same layering in the base R plot example above?

Comment: What are you doing is defining a symbology style in both layers. You need to understand the difference between the raster layer value and raster symbology. If you need to preserve the result, export the plot result instead of creating a new raster with RBG colors

Comment: You cannot easily do what you have in mind. The best you can do is export the plot itself, but only as a standard tiff, jpeg, etc..., not a georeferenced raster. Back in the old day we would map color saturation to a hillshade for overlays (eg., elevation) and then export as an RGB image that was georeferenced. I would have to dig up 20 year old code to recall how to do this. Why would you need this as a georeferenced image as it is a easily recreated in the plot environment?

Comment: @aldo_tapia thanks for your message. I need georeferenced output, so unfortunately simply exploring the plot would not help me get the output I require.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyEvans, I have many raster files that require hillshade overlain by my desired colour ramp so all of my colleagues can view these images in GUI driven GIS software along with their other layers and point datasets without having to manually change the aesthetics in the GUI, or layer rasters with transparency in the GUI. 
I have written a loop to reprocess all my raster images as georeferenced tiffs (with the colour palette written into the saved GeoTiff), and would like to share GeoTiffs that have the aesthetics provided by the plot environment.

Comment: @chipsin check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66708444/sf-create-geopdf-using-ggplot2-output-object) in SO

Comment: Thanks @aldo_tapia but unfortunately this works with ggplot2 objects (with the line work, etc). I want to layer and export a GeoTiff which can be opened in GIS software without the linework and other outputs from ggplot

Comment: @chipsin use `theme_void()`. You can remove axis, ticks, legend, labels, etc. ggplot is fully customizable

Comment: @aldo_tapia, thank you soo much. Your earlier link and this has completely solved my issues!